# PowerShell to re-run the users logon script

Tags: powershell, vbscript, login-script

I have a VBScript that re-runs the users login script, I use Task Scheduler to trigger the script to run whenever the user's network status changes. (to ensure drives are mapped when necessary).  I'm looking to convert this into PowerShell but am getting stumped. How would you do it?

This is the VBScript I'm using:

```vb
Dim objNet
Dim wshShell
Dim wshProcess

Dim domain, username, dc

Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.NetWork") 
Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set wshProcess = wshShell.Environment("Process")

Domain = objNet.UserDomain
UserName = objNet.UserName
DC = wshProcess("LogonServer")

Set UserObj = GetObject("WinNT://" & domain & "/" & username)

loginScript = DC & "\netlogon\" & UserObj.LoginScript

On Error Resume Next
wshShell.Run(loginscript)

Set UserObj = Nothing
Set wshProcess = Nothing
Set wshShell = Nothing
Set objNet = Nothing
```

Comment: Short answer: Not. From my point of view, it's already broken, if you need to remap your drives. By the way: This is not a code translation service. Show own effort.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [Related](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee221101.aspx).

Comment: Using logon scripts for network drives is very labour intensive and is now antiquated. [Group Policy Preferences](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/01/07/using-group-policy-preferences-to-map-drives-based-on-group-membership/) is a much better way to do this as you can target drives much more precisely using various filters, group membership and OU being popular. And because User Policy refreshes itself during the users session, if they remove drives it will re-map them.

Comment: @JamesC. I agree in general, but in my experience configuring network drive mappings via GPP doesn't work well for mobile computers (logon stalls and eventually throws an error when the user computer isn't connected to the domain).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Interesting I've not come across that issue without our implementations. But now with W10 and DirectAccess lack of connectivity is unusual as most users have Wifi or 4G.

Comment: @JamesC. I have found it common that mobile device GPP drive mappings are WMI or security group filtered to not apply. For better or worse I've then seen GPP'd desktop shortcuts to run drive mapping scripts for the mobile devices to be run by the user post vpn connection. But if I remember correctly the timeout a drive mapping failing is about 5 seconds, which depending on the number of failed mappings can be a lot of extra logon time.

Answer (score 1):

Too late to help the OP, but I figured out how to do it in PowerShell if anyone else needs it.

```
$ObjNet = New-Object -ComObject WScript.NetWork
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$WshProcess = $WshShell.Environment('Process')
$Domain = $ObjNet.UserDomain
$UserName = $ObjNet.UserName
$DC = $WshProcess['LogonServer']
$UserObj = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Domain/$UserName"

& cmd /c CALL "$DC\netlogon\$($UserObj.LoginScript)"
```